# If the measure of X is infinity and fn converges to 0 a.e. then is it true that fn converges to 0 in measure?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, almost-everywhere

I was thinking of the example in Folland on page 61 i.e. $\mu(\mathbb{R})=\infty$. Let $f_n=n\chi_{[0,1/n]}\rightarrow 0$ a.e. Then $f_n\rightarrow 0$ in measure. My inclination is that this is true so it requires proof. Also the same question is asked but for when $\mu(X)=1$. My inclination is that this is not true and a counterexample can be provided.

Comment: That $f_n \to 0$ is $\mu$-measure _signifies_ that $f_n > c$ has $\mu$-measure that tends to zero as $n \to \infty.$ This can happen, for example, if $f_n$ grows in a region that has small measure or if $f_n$ decays fast in a region with a lot of measure (or combinations of both).

Answer (score 0):

The statement that convergence a.e. implies convergence in measure is true in finite measure spaces, not true in general.

For the first statement, note $f_n\to f$ a.e. implies for all $\varepsilon>0$ and $x\in X$, there exists $n$ such that $k\geq n$ implies $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon$. In particular, this implies
$$\bigcap_n\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{x\in X:|f_k(x)-f(x)|\geq\varepsilon\}=\emptyset.$$
Finiteness of the measure space gives lets us use continuity from above to yield
$$\lim_n \mu\left(\bigcup_{k\geq n}\{x\in X:|f_k(x)-f(x)|\geq\varepsilon\}\right)=0$$
which implies convergence in measure.

To see how this fails in general measure spaces, consider $f_n=\mathbf{1}_{(-\infty,n]}$, which converges to $1$ everywhere but not in measure.